# Ngrx feature selector returns memorized function

Tags: angular, ngrx

I did everything step by step ad [ngrx docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md) says but in the end instead value I'm getting memorized function. I went thru github issues but seems to me I did everything correct, so could anybody help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

my code below

app.index.ts

```
import {ActionReducer, createFeatureSelector, createSelector, MetaReducer} from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromCategories from '../categories/store/categories.index';

export interface State {
  categoryState: fromCategories.State
}

export const reducers = {
  categoryState: fromCategories.categoryReducers
};

export const selectCategoriesFeature = createFeatureSelector<fromCategories.State>('categoryState');
export const selectCategoriesFeatureArray = createSelector(selectCategoriesFeature, (state: fromCategories.State) => state.categories);
```

categories.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
   ...
    StoreModule.forFeature('categoryState', categoryReducers),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([CategoriesEffects]),
  ],
...
```

categories.index.ts

```
import {Category} from '../categories';
import * as categoryReducer from './categories.reducer';

export interface State {
  categories: Category[]
}

export const categoryReducers = categoryReducer.reducer;
```

categroies.reducer.ts

```
import * as CategoriesActions from './categories.actions';
import {State} from './categories.index';

export type Action = CategoriesActions.All;

const initialState: State = {
  categories: null
};

export function reducer (state = initialState, action: Action): State {

  switch (action.type) {

    // GET CATEGORIES LIST

    case CategoriesActions.GET_CATEGORIES: {return state}
    case CategoriesActions.GET_CATEGORIES_ERROR: {return state}
    case CategoriesActions.GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS: {
      initialState.categories = action.payload;
      return Object.assign({}, initialState);
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

categories.actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import {Category} from '../categories';

// *******************************************************************

// const

export const GET_CATEGORIES  = '[Category] Get items';
export const GET_CATEGORIES_ERROR = '[Category] Get items error';
export const GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS  = '[Category] Get items success';

// get categories

export class GetCategories implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_CATEGORIES;
  constructor(public payload?: any) {}
}

export class GetCategoriesError implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_CATEGORIES_ERROR;
  constructor(public payload: Response) {}
}

export class GetCategoriesSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS;
  constructor(public payload: Category[]) {}
}

export type All
  = GetCategories
  | GetCategoriesError
  | GetCategoriesSuccess
```

categories.component.ts

```
import * as fromRoot from '../store/app.index';
import {selectCategoriesFeatureArray} from '../store/app.index';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.css']
})

export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$: any;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(selectCategoriesFeatureArray)
  }
}
```

and this is what console log returns

> ƒ memoized() {
>           if (!lastArguments) {
>               lastResult = t.apply(null, arguments);
>               lastArguments = arguments;
>               return lastResult;
>           }
>           for (var /** @typ…

Comment: `createSelector` returns a a memoized function that you should pass to `store.select(...)` to return an observable slice of state. So it is working as expected. What you probably want is `this.store.select(selectCategoriesFeatureArray)`. Then you can subscribe to it in some way.

Comment: @bygrace thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for...